# I need to know if the data has been added to the Cloud Firestore (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this operation

```
EventModel data = EventModel(_nameEvent, _passEvent, _localEvent, _dateEventString);
HashMap<String, String> mapData = data.getEventMap();
Firestore.instance.collection("app").document("database_v1").collection("events").document().setData(mapData);
```

I need to show a warning if the data was entered successfully or if it was not

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
                              SnackBar(
                                  content: Text(message),
                                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 6)
                              )
                          );
```

I tried to use .whenComplete() and then(doc), but none returns if it was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`setData` method](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/setData.html) returns a `Future<void>`, which completes when the document has been committed to the server. This means you can just `await` the `setData` call:

```
await Firestore.instance
               .collection("app").document("database_v1")
               .collection("events").document().setData(mapData);
```